# YouTube API request not working when I'm logged in

Tags: angularjs, http, youtube-api, cors, yeoman-generator

I'm using Yeoman's [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator to do login and authentication.

When I comment out the code for authentication and make YouTube API requests, it works perfectly. But when I uncomment the authentication code, log in, and make the same YouTube API request, it doesn't work.

Here's what's happening:

[image]

Somehow it's making the same API request (to `videos?part=...`) twice. When I'm not logged in it only happens once.

So the first one is successful:

[image]

But the second one is unsuccessful:

[image]

I have two questions:

1) Why is a second HTTP request being generated?

Here is an excerpt of the code used to make the request:

```
console.log('before request');
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id='+videoId+'&key='+API_KEY)
  .success(function(result) {
    console.log('success');
    var item = result.items[0];
    vm.skim.title = item.snippet.title;
    vm.skim.description = item.snippet.description;
```

"before request" only gets logged once, and I can't figure out what is generating the second HTTP request.

2) Why is the second HTTP request unsuccessful? The only difference between the requests seems to be that Authorization header. I don't know much about this, but it seems to be a [request with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials), and from what I understand, the fact that the response has `access-control-allow-credentials: true` should make this work.

I'm not sure what code I should post, so [here](https://github.com/adamzerner/skimmable-videos) is all of it on GitHub.

Edit: Here is what a successful request looks like when I comment out the authorization code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first request is a "preflight request" : an `OPTION` request to make sure that the remote server allows you to make the real request (the browser expects a `access-control-allow-origin`). It seems strange that you only have it when trying a logged query, but that may be a side effect of `access-control-max-age` : that the cache duration of this preflight request.

The second request is the real `POST`. The [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#client-side-apps) says :

> The API returns an HTTP 401 response code (Unauthorized) if you submit a request to access a protected resource with an access token that is expired, bogus, improperly scoped, or invalid for some other reason.

You should check the "Calling the YouTube Data API" part to see if your token is valid and if a [sample request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests) works.

About the `access-control-allow-credentials` : the default behavior is to **not** send any cookie (and won't without this header), you can send them with `$http.get('...', {withCredentials: true})`.

Comment: "After obtaining an access token for a user, your application can use that token to submit authorized API requests on that user's behalf." - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication. I don't want to submit the API request on the user's behalf. I want to submit it the same way it's submitted when they're not logged in. `var req = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id='+videoId+'&key='+API_KEY,
      headers: {
        Authorization: undefined
      }
    };
    $http(req)`. Didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. There's an interceptor in the boilerplate I'm using that adds the Authorization header.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. How did you fix it in the boilerplate? I am using Angular full stack and have noticed that the authInterceptor is causing problems when I call youtube, but I can't figure out how to fix it,